# MySQL on Linux out of memory

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, memory

#### OS: Redhat Enterprise Linux Server Release 5.3 (Tikanga)

#### Architecture: Intel Xeon 64Bit

#### MySQL Server 5.5.20 Enterprise Server advanced edition.

#### Application: Liferay.

**My database size is 200MB. RAM is 64GB.**
The memory consumption increases gradually and we **run out of memory**.
Then only rebooting releases all the memory, but then process of memory consumption starts again and reaches 63-64GB in less than a day.

*Parameters detail*:

#### key_buffer_size=16M

#### innodb_buffer_pool_size=3GB

#### inndb_buffer_pool_instances=3

#### max_connections=1000

#### innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

#### innodb_change_buffering=inserts

#### read_buffer_size=2M

#### read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

It's a serious production server issue that I am facing.
What could be the reason behind this and how to resolve.

**This is the report of 2pm today, after Linux was rebooted yesterday @ around 10pm.**

Output of free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64455      22053      42402          0       1544       1164
-/+ buffers/cache:      19343      45112
Swap:        74998          0      74998
```

Output of vmstat 2 5

```
   procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------    
   r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
   0  0      0 43423976 1583700 1086616    0    0     1   173   22   27  1  1 98  0  0
   2  0      0 43280200 1583712 1228636    0    0     0   146 1265  491  2  2 96  1  0
   0  0      0 43421940 1583724 1087160    0    0     0   138 1469  738  2  1 97  0  0
   1  0      0 43422604 1583728 1086736    0    0     0  5816 1615  934  1  1 97  0  0
   0  0      0 43422372 1583732 1086752    0    0     0  2784 1323  545  2  1 97  0  0
```

Output of top -n 3 -b

```
top - 14:16:22 up 16:32,  5 users,  load average: 0.79, 0.77, 0.93
Tasks: 345 total,   1 running, 344 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  0.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.1%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  66002772k total, 22656292k used, 43346480k free,  1582152k buffers
Swap: 76798724k total,        0k used, 76798724k free,  1163616k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                     
 6434 mysql     15   0 4095m 841m 5500 S 113.5  1.3 426:53.69 mysqld                     
    1 root      15   0 10344  680  572 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.09 init                        
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0                 
    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                 
    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                  
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/1
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a typical case of `HELP! Linux Ate My RAM!` ( http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ ) or do you have _actual_ problems? Does the server swap itself to death? Slow down to a crawl within a day? Something else terrible?

Comment: I have checked indexes, set parameters as suggested by MySQL Support team, but in vain.. :(

Comment: You didn't actually reply my question. :-)

Comment: no it's not the case of linuxatemyram.

Comment: Are you sure that it is MySQL that eat the RAM ? check with top or ps. There is maybe something else. Check your system logs to see if another daemon start to cry

Comment: I have checked the logs, everything seems to be fine. I have been checking memory usage through top, free -m and sar -r. As I mentioned earlier it increases gradually and reaches 64GB in less than a day..

Comment: @sunrays *have you checked the **size of the individusl processes** on your system using top* which is what Dom was suggesting? Is MySQL the largest? Is it the one growing over time? (MySQL is usually good about not having memory leaks. It's very likely your culprit is something else - you need to look at individual processes, not just aggregate usage)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `free -m`.

Comment: @voretaq7,Erika: I have pasted the output of free -m, vmstat and top for your reference.

Comment: I see nothing in what you posted that even hints that you have a problem and even less to implicate MySQL as the cause of it. Exactly what is the problem and why do you point the finger at MySQL? Memory *usage* is not a problem in itself.

Comment: @John I am not saying that MySQL is the cause.My concern is the site goes down when whole RAM is consumed.We are using Liferay and last night we set two parameters in that : testOnBorrow=''true' and validationQuery="SELECT". I guess it's for connection pooling. Today @ one point of time the RAM jumped from 24GB to 64GB in just 10mins. And for a change the swapped memory was used(20GB). and after 10mins the RAM and Swap memory decreased to 4GB and 500MB resp. And the site didnt go down. But the memory is increasing gradually again. Is it a thing to worry????

Comment: @sunrays (a) You have to post data from when you're having a problem. When the system is working fine (as it appears to be in your posted data) there's nothing to see.  (b) Please sort your `top` output by VIRTual size (see `man top` for information on how to change the sort order).  The default sort for `top` is by CPU usage, which is not helpful here, nor are aggregate memory statistics (`free`, `vmstat`, `top`'s header) -- You need to isolate a ***specific process**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and basically I changed the mysqltuner.pl script and made it more verbose and know what happened.

Basically, the memory usage, if you are using any variation of `my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf` config file, the major part of memory using will be nearly like this:

```
memory usage = min(tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size) 
    + key_buffer_size + query_cache_size 
    + innodb_buffer_pool_size + innodb_additional_mem_pool_size + innodb_log_buffer_size
    + (max_connections * 
        (read_buffer_size + read_rnd_buffer_size 
           + sort_buffer_size + thread_stack + join_buffer_size
        )
    )
```

This sum have not all factors, please refer mysqltuner.pl script code (and run it) to see them all.

So, it seems you need to lower a lot `read_buffer_size`, `read_rnd_buffer_size`, `sort_buffer_size`, `thread_stack` and `join_buffer_size`, since its sum is multiplied by 1000 from `max_connections`.

Other solution is to lower a little bit the `max_connections` number. With this huge memory for thread buffers, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and all InnoDB related variables becomes a minor issue.

You can also try to figure out if your applications really a huge amount of `sort_buffer_size` and `join_buffer_size`. If not, put these values down.

Hope it helped.

Comment: @ Lucas
Thanks for the suggestions. 
Actually the problem was with the Application, where the connections was not releasing memory even after the connection was closed.
The application is liferay and as I mentioned earlier we set two parameters in that : testOnBorrow=''true' and validationQuery="SELECT".
Now the server is stable.
Still I would keep your points in mind.. :)

Comment: @ Lucas I tried executing the mysqltuner.pl script but didnt get any output. It would be nice if you could give a link or share a document on how to use it..

Comment: @Sunrays you only need to have perl installed at your server. Install perl, download mysqltuner (`# wget http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl`) and run `perl mysqltuner.pl` . It will ask you MySQL's user and password, will run some tests and suggest you what you could tune up in your server. But be careful, run at the same time in other tty some memory monitor, like `htop` to take care if mysqltuner do something that eats much memory.